# Radius of convergence of series $\sum^\infty_{n=0} 3^{-n} (2 \pi)^{-n} (\arctan n)^n x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Is it correct that the convergence radius of the series $\sum^\infty_{n=0} 3^{-n} (2 \pi)^{-n} (\arctan n)^n x^n$ equals $12$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way: because $\arctan{n} \to \pi/2$ as $n \to \infty$, then the $n$th term of the sum approaches

$$\left ( \frac{(\pi/2) x}{3 \cdot 2 \pi}\right )^n  = \left (\frac{x}{12} \right )^n$$

As a geometric sum over some $y$ (i.e., $\sum y^n$) has a radius of convergence of $1$, this sum has a radius of convergence of $12$.

Answer (score 2):

The radius is the limit of $\frac 1 {\sqrt[n] { {(6 \pi)} ^{-n} {(\arctan n)} ^n}}$, which is indeed $12$.